# How to get more than 3 levels of nesting in mdframed environments?

Tags: highlighting, mdframed, nesting

Before I get to many of "don't do this as it does not look good", I have two modes of my documents:

1. *Final mode*: where there is ONLY one level of nested `mdframed`
2. *Review mode*: where there are numerous levels of nested `mdframed`, each one indicating information needed during the review process relevant to the text within the `mdframed`.

So, this requested usage is ONLY for my review mode.

The code below produces

[image]

But, Un-commenting out the two lines in the code yields

> LaTeX Error: Too deeply nested.

I would like to get a larger number of nesting?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Outer Title 1},backgroundcolor=orange!25]
    \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 2},backgroundcolor=cyan!25]
        \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 3},backgroundcolor=yellow!25]
            %\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 4},backgroundcolor=green]
            %\end{mdframed}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to increase the number of list levels defined. Simply loading `enumitem` would do it, but there's also a way to do it without loading a heavy package.

Comment: @PaulGessler: Dammnn!! That works. BUT I am already including `enumitem` in my actual use case, that means that this is NOT going to solve my real problem...

Comment: So you have additional nesting in your actual usage that puts you once again over the nesting limit?

Comment: @PaulGessler: Seems I can nest up to depth of 9 with `enumitem`, but I don't think I am exceeding that level.  Back to figuring out what is going on in my actual use case. BTW, I think your suggestion is _an_ answer.

Comment: But not _the_ answer... ;-)

Comment: @PaulGessler The answer - just not to *the* question?

Comment: Why does loading `enumitem` help exactly? If I nest `itemize` environments too deeply, for example, just loading `enumitem` makes no difference. I know it makes it possible to define additional levels but just loading it does not seem to do that. So I'm curious as to why it should help in the case of `mdframed`.

Comment: @cfr the reason is the redefinition of `\@toodeep` made by `enumitem`: `\def\@toodeep{%
  \ifnum\@listdepth>\enit@listdepth\relax
    \enit@toodeep
  \else
    \count@\@listdepth
    \global\advance\@listdepth\@ne
    \@ifundefined{@list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth}%
      {\expandafter\let
         \csname @list\romannumeral\the\@listdepth\expandafter\endcsname
         \csname @list\romannumeral\the\count@\endcsname}{}%
  \fi}` This doesn't affect standard lists, but any non-standard environment (`mdframed`, in particular) controlling the nesting levels with `\@toodeep` will now allow...

Comment: more nesting levels.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mdframed.sty` has

```
\ifnum\mdf@envdepth >\tw@\@toodeep\else
```

in the definition of `\mdf@preenvsetting` and this prevents more than three levels of nesting. You can change this with a patch to the command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\mdf@preenvsetting}
  {\mdf@envdepth >\tw@}
  {\mdf@envdepth >20}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Outer Title 1},backgroundcolor=orange!25]
    \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 2},backgroundcolor=cyan!25]
        \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 3},backgroundcolor=yellow!25]
            \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 4},backgroundcolor=green]
              \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 5},backgroundcolor=magenta!20]
                \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 6},backgroundcolor=olive!20]
                  \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 7},backgroundcolor=red!80!black]
                    \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 8},backgroundcolor=gray!50]
                      \begin{mdframed}[frametitle={Inner Title 9},backgroundcolor=blue!40]
                      \end{mdframed}
                    \end{mdframed}
                  \end{mdframed}
                \end{mdframed}
              \end{mdframed}
            \end{mdframed}
        \end{mdframed}
    \end{mdframed}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]